# what do css classes like my-2, my-lg-0, mr-sm-2 do in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have looked at other questions and the bootstrap documentation and cant seem to find out what these classes do to elements. Any help is appreciated! Im just trying to make my search bar be 1/4th the size on a large viewport, 1/3 the size on a medium viewport, and 100% the size on a small viewport!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Those are bootstrap spacing utilities classes :

`mr-sm-2`:

> r - for classes that set `margin-right` or `padding-right`

`my-2`, `my-lg-0`:

> y - for classes that set both `*-top` and `*-bottom`

the `m`

> m - for classes that set margin

you can see the notation from boostrap spacing [**here**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#notation)

---

`sm` and `lg` are utilities classes that everyone who uses bootstrap are use to see it:

`sm` - small

`lg` - large

Comment: Is that means my-2 is equal to my-lg-2? **lg** here is just for other programmers to see?

Comment: @Sam `sm` and `lg` target small and large viewports. Without those modifiers you're targeting all viewports.